# Perl scripting to get "Wanted Data"

Tags: perl, scripting

I have data like below:

Source file: `input.txt` containing many records with a format like this:

```
09.05.2014 09.49.52:359 RID:routerNode1@app1:1662306081,msisdn:787887225696,sid:93889095007001,tid:1405090902095648846024000,status:2,time:20140509094952,reasonELIVRD,refund:null,status2:null
```

`output1.txt`:

```
09.05.2014,09.49.52,routerNode1@app1:1662306081,787887225696,93889095007001,1405090902095648846024000,2,20140509094952
```

`output2.txt`

```
09-05-2014,09-49-52,routerNode1@app1:1662306081,787887225696,93889095007001,1405090902095648846024000,2,20140509094952
```

Please help me to build the perl program to read from input file and then write to the output file.

this code read from the line, not yet read from input file. But still problem

data given is not truedata given is not truedata given is not truedata given is not true,787887225696,93889095007001,1405090902095648846024000,2,20140509094952

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use warnings;  
use strict;  

my $str = <<'_STR_';  
09.05.2014 09.49.52:359 RID:routerNode1@app1:1662306081,msisdn:787887225696,sid:93889095007001,tid:1405090902095648846024000,status:2,time:20140509094952,reason:DELIVRD,refund:null,status2:null  

_STR_  



my $wanted_data;  
for ( split /,/, $str ) { 
    if (/(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}' '\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}).+RID:(\d+)/sm) {  
        my ( $format_date, $rid )= ( $1, $2 );  
        $format_date =~ s/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1-$2-$3/;  
        $wanted_data .= $format_date . ',' . $rid;  
    }  
    elsif (/msisdn:(.+)/) {  
        $wanted_data .= ',' . $1;  
    }  
    elsif (/sid:(.+)/) {  
        $wanted_data .= ',' . $1;  
    }  
    elsif (/tid:(.+)/) {  
        $wanted_data .= ',' . $1;  
    }  
    elsif (/status:(.+)/) {  
        $wanted_data .= ',' . $1;  
    }  
    elsif (/time:(.+)/) {  
        $wanted_data .= ',' . $1;  
    }  
    else{ print "data given is not true"}  
}  

print $wanted_data, $/;
```

Comment: Can you include the code you've used to try and tackle this so far?

Comment: i cannot copy the code ... always error format ...

Comment: The idea is that you'd include the code you're trying to use, that way people here can help with small tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
   my @out;
   my @fld=split(/,/);
   my ($format_date, $rid)=$fld[0]=~/(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}).+RID:(.*)$/;  
   badInput() if ! defined $format_date;
   my @f=split(" ",$format_date);
   push(@out,$f[0]=~s/\./-/gr);
   push(@out,$f[1]=~s/\./-/gr);
   push(@out,$rid);
   my $i=1;
   for (qw(msisdn sid tid status time)) {
      my ($id)=$fld[$i++]=~/$_:(.*)$/;
      badInput() if ! defined $id;
      push(@out,$id);
   }
   print join(",",@out)."\n";

}

sub badInput {
   die "Data given is not true!";
}
```

Comment: Bareword found where operator expected at ./noel2.pl line 11, near "s/\./-/gr"
    Bareword found where operator expected at ./noel2.pl line 12, near "s/\./-/gr"
    syntax error at ./noel2.pl line 11, near "s/\./-/gr"
    syntax error at ./noel2.pl line 12, near "s/\./-/gr"

Comment: @user2253805 Maybe this is related to the version of perl you are running. Type `perl -v`. The nondestructive modifier `r` was introduced in perl version 5.14. [Regex substitution modifier /r](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1008916)

Comment: $ perl -v

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Copyright 1987-2006, Larry Wall

Comment: That is a very old version of perl. I would recommend that you upgrade to version 5.18, or at least version 5.14. Are you using Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: Linux RH .. sorry if that is too old

Comment: Ok, if you do not want to upgrade, you can just change the code slightly. For example: `$a=$b=~s/test//gr` becomes `$a=$b; $a=~s/test//g`. So the `r` modifier is just a convenient short hand introduced in v5.14.